# SQL FIFO Inventory with fractional quantities

Tags: sql, t-sql, fifo, inventory, inventory-management

I've found a ton of useful links here and at other sites on how to implement FIFO running totals and costs in SQL. They seem to fall into two categories, the beans in a jar work table approach and the more exotic but exponentially faster CTE approach.

This is a pretty good article that covers both:

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/set-based-speed-phreakery-the-fifo-stock-inventory-sql-problem/

Here's the rub - my client uses fractional quantities. So an inventory transaction can be 24.13342 square yards of something. Has anyone worked with FIFO Inventory in SQL with fractional quantities? I'm having trouble finding anything on it and from what I'm understanding so far, this kind of breaks the examples I'm coming across.

Comment: Running totals also work on floats, etc., you should be able to apply the same logic.

Comment: Are you planning on using [`decimal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx), or one of the vague floating point types? Are there other constraints, e.g. you can't have less than one seventh of a wig or remnants of less than one cubic groat are discarded?

Comment: Decimal out the 6 places.

Answer (score 1):

I have been seeking a FIFO query which is efficient and simple enough to understand. Sadly i couldn t find any so i made my own.

Here how it works;

First of all we need two views(or tables or table returning functions or whatever you like..) as "BUYING" and "SELLING" like;

```
CREATE TABLE FIFO_BUYING(
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[UNITID] [int] NOT NULL,
[DATE] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
[UNIT_PRICE] [money] NOT NULL,
[QUANTITY] [float] NOT NULL,
[CUMULATIVE_QUANTITY] [float] NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE FIFO_SELLING(
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[UNITID] [int] NOT NULL,
[DATE] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
[UNIT_PRICE] [money] NOT NULL,
[QUANTITY] [float] NOT NULL,
[CUMULATIVE_QUANTITY] [float] NOT NULL)

insert into FIFO_BUYING([UNITID],[DATE],[UNIT_PRICE],[QUANTITY],[CUMULATIVE_QUANTITY]) values
(1,'2015-01-01 16:01',100.0,2.0,2.0),
(1,'2015-01-08 13:40',105.0,4.0,6.0),
(1,'2015-01-08 14:11',102.0,2.0,8.0),
(1,'2015-01-12 14:00',101.0,7.0,15.0),
(1,'2015-01-14 17:55',103.0,5.0,20.0)

insert into FIFO_SELLING([UNITID],[DATE],[UNIT_PRICE],[QUANTITY],[CUMULATIVE_QUANTITY]) values
(1,'2015-01-02 10:21',150.0,1.0,1.0),
(1,'2015-01-08 13:45',140.0,3.0,4.0),
(1,'2015-01-10 17:30',145.0,3.0,7.0),
(1,'2015-01-10 17:55',130.0,5.0,12.0),
(1,'2015-01-15 12:15',135.0,6.0,18.0)
```

The field named CUMULATIVE_QUANTITY is supposed to sum QUANTITY cumulatively from the begining for each row which helps us find what to sell next.

can also be calculated as select QUANTITY,CUM=sum(QUANTITY) over (partition by UNITID order by DATE) from FIFO_BUYING

anyway..

```
select 
BUYING_ID=B.ID,
SELLING_ID=S.ID,
BUYING_DATE=B.[DATE],
SELLING_DATE=S.[DATE],
QUANTITY=(case when S.CUMULATIVE_QUANTITY<B.CUMULATIVE_QUANTITY then S.CUMULATIVE_QUANTITY else B.CUMULATIVE_QUANTITY end) 
                - isnull(lag(case when S.CUMULATIVE_QUANTITY<B.CUMULATIVE_QUANTITY then S.CUMULATIVE_QUANTITY else B.CUMULATIVE_QUANTITY end) 
                    over (order by case when S.CUMULATIVE_QUANTITY<B.CUMULATIVE_QUANTITY then S.CUMULATIVE_QUANTITY else B.CUMULATIVE_QUANTITY end),0.0),
BUYING_UNIT_PRICE=B.UNIT_PRICE,
SELLING_UNIT_PRICE=S.UNIT_PRICE,
PROFIT_PER_UNIT=S.UNIT_PRICE-B.UNIT_PRICE
from
(select top 1000000 * from FIFO_BUYING order by [DATE]) B join
(select top 1000000 * from FIFO_SELLING order by [DATE]) S on 
B.CUMULATIVE_QUANTITY-B.QUANTITY<S.CUMULATIVE_QUANTITY and
S.CUMULATIVE_QUANTITY-S.QUANTITY<B.CUMULATIVE_QUANTITY
```

first trick is to join which connects the right rows with each other and removes pointless connections between those views (at the and it was a full join.)..

we make sure both views ordered by date inside final query, not necessary if you already done that inside the views..

second trick is to calculate the right quantity since there are 2 different comes from buying and selling.. lag function helps us alot couse we need to compare current row with the one brfore that..

this worked way faster than fetch next for me..